# How to redirect android logging to stdout?

Tags: java, android, logging

For testing an android application, we rely on logging which is saved as an xml file. I want to be able to direct standard android logging (android.util.Log) to be saved in this way. I'm currently able to store System.out.print and System.err.print in this xml format, so it would probably be easiest if there was a way to redirect android logging to stdout. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not use logcat -f "filename" instead?

Comment: Is this possible from android test code?